# Does Intel Smart Response cache drive size matter?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, cache, smart-response

I have a Lenovo Y400 laptop, that came with a 16gb Intel Smart Response cache drive. I also have an unused 64gb ssd drive lying around. 
I was wondering whether replacing the 16gb cache drive with the 64 drive will show any significant performance improvements, if any at all? Has someone conducted a benchmark comparing Smart Response performance by cache size?

Comment: Not an answer but the cache SSD in that notebook is most likely not going to be a regular notebook SSD, it'll be a mSATA card.  Is your 64GB SSD also mSATA, or have you confirmed that the 16GB in the notebook is in fact a regular SSD drive?

Comment: Good point... The cache drive is mSATA, and the spare SSD is SATA. *sigh* I'm still curious about the theoretical difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Intel Smart Response Technology's caching [supports up to 64 GB](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/02/12/feature_what_the_best_solid_state_disk_configuration/).

A larger cache means more of your data can be stored on the SSD, and when used (i.e. read), will open faster.  The difference between cache sizes isn't something you can benchmark in the traditional sense.  It would depend entirely on you've previously been using; whether or not what you're opening next has been used before, or whether you've used too many other things since then that resulted in it being flushed out.